# What is the correct syntax for declaring a class that implements two interfaces

Tags: java

I'm writing a class that should implement two interfaces, DNARecord and Comparable.

When I I do something like

```
 public class FastqRecord implements DNARecord  Comparable<FastaRecord>{}
```

the class does not compile.

If I do this

```
 public class FastqRecord implements DNARecord  {}
```

it works, but I don't know what to do with Comparable. Should I put it on the constructor or how do I add it to the class declaration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an interface extend multiple interfaces in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546357/can-an-interface-extend-multiple-interfaces-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Implement multiple interfaces by separating them with commas.

```
public class FastqRecord implements DNARecord, Compareable<FastaRecord>
{
}
```

This has nothing to do with a constructor though.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the comma:

```
public class FastqRecord implements DNARecord,  Compareable<FastaRecord>{}
```