# Interface implementation by both parent and sub class in java

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, abstract, object-oriented-analysis

If the base class and sub class implements the same interface and the method implementation of the abstract method is provided in the base class then do we have to provide the implementation in sub class also?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and the implementation from subclass executes when you have initialisation paradigm

```
BaseClass v = new SubClass();
```

That's quite normal polymorphism/ovveriding.

Related : [Can an interface extend multiple interfaces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546357/can-an-interface-extend-multiple-interfaces-in-java)

Comment: What if the overridden method in parent class is private?

Comment: If you try to make private, you see a compiler error Because you are reducing the visibility of the method.

Answer (score 1):

> do we have to provide the implementation in sub class also

No, you don't **have to** do it. If one class `extends` another, it already has all (`public` and `protected`) methods declared in parent class.

But you **can** provide a different implementation of this method. In this case the method from the parent class will be overriden.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of implementing the same interface in both parent and child classes as because if you are implementing it in parent class then child will also have the same method but if you want to override you can override it.

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw();
}

class Parallelogram implements Shape {
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("This is Parallelogram");
    }
}

public class Square extends Parallelogram {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("This Parallelogram is Square");
    }

    public static void main(String args[0]) {

        Square square = new Square();
        square.draw();
    }

}
```

//Output
This Parallelogram is Square

```
public class Rhombus extends Parallelogram {

    public static void main(String args[0]) {

        Rhombus rhombus = new Rhombus();
        rhombus.draw();
    }
}
```

//Output
This is Parallelogram

Answer (score 0):

It should not be required as subclass already has the method implementation in base class

Comment: What if the subclass have a different implementation for the same ?

Comment: Then you can override that method in child class too